# Proper syntax for executing a function only if another function is successful

Tags: python, function, syntax, if-statement

I have the following code that is part of my email class that I use in my programs.  Currently I am running the quit function whether or not a connection to the SMTP server was made in the connect function.  I know I could put the quit function inside of the try statement after the email is sent, but I would like to figure out how to write the code to say the equivalent of "if a connection to the server is open, close it."  What is the best way to write that in Python?

Thanks!

```
def connect(self, headers, msg):

    try:
        self.server.starttls()

        try:
            self.server.login(self.usrname,self.pswd)

            try:
                self.server.sendmail(self.sendfrom, self.sendto, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + msg)
            except Exception as sendmailfail:
                print(sendmailfail)

        except Exception as emailfail:
            print (emailfail)

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)

def quit(self):
    self.server.quit()
    print("The SMTP connection is closed")



first = GmailSmpt('x','y','z','zz')
x , y = first.message()
first.connect(x,y)
first.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to finish the ["Errors and Exceptions" section of the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

```
try:
  possibly_fail()
except ...:
  handle_exception()
else:
  no_exceptions()
finally:
  always_run_this()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I inserted an else clause into my connection try statement and it works.